# How do I make an LWJGL window resizable?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I am trying to make the window of my java game resizable, which uses the LWJGL library. According to some forum questions that date back from 2007 this is only possible with a workaround. Is this still the case today? And what is the way to go?

Comment: UPDATE: LWJGL has in recent versions added a bunch of function calls to the Display class that allow you to make the window resizable and maximizable. I can recommend that method over using a canvas/JFrame combo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using LWJGL 2.9 you can call

```
Display.setResizable();
```

This will allow the window to be resized.

Then before you update the display do this.

```
if (Display.wasResized()) GL11.glViewport(0, 0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
```

this will change the viewport to be the size of the screen if it was resized.

Comment: No means to bump, but for those who find this question, this is (currently) the best answer to date.

Comment: The `Display.setResizable()` method takes a boolean argument: `true` to make it resizable, or `false` to stop it from being resizable.

Answer (score 25):

The Display class has the option for enabling resizing.
http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setResizable(boolean)

You can get the width and height at anytime with `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`.

Comment: Indeed. This was recently added as a new feature. I can highly recommend to use this rather than the old "canvas" method.

Comment: Broken link - leads to 404 not found

Answer (score 6):

LWJGL's native display is not resizable. However its easy to achieve you simply use an AWT Frame and using Display.setParent(Canvas) stick your LWJGL content on it to get a resizeable window.

Comment: I got a similar answer on the IRC channel of LWJGL. thanks for the reply here :)
The one who helped me with it also showed an implementation of this method in one of his own programs. For those interested, you can find it here:
http://hg.l33tlabs.org/twlthemeeditor/file/tip/src/de/matthiasmann/twlthemeeditor/Main.java