# Lwjgl/openGL window size always stays the same despite changing width and height

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

For some reason the size if the window always stays the same size even when i change the width and the height.  I think the problem is something to the viewport as the viewable area in the window changes correctly but there's always a black area in the part of the window that is not used.  I've probably expalained this really badly but any help would be much appreciated.

I've put a screenshot of the window below..

```
public class DisplayExample
{

    private int     width           = 800;
    private int     height          = 600;
    private int     colourDepth     = 32;
    private String  windowTitle     = "My First Window";
    public boolean  closeRequested  = false;
    private boolean fullscreen      = false;

    private float rtri = 0.0f;
    private float rquad = 0.0f;

    public void start()
    {

        createWindow(windowTitle, width, height, colourDepth, fullscreen);
        initGL();

        while (!closeRequested)
        {
            pollInput();
            updateLogic();
            renderGL();

            Display.update(); // flushes OpenGL pipeline and swaps back and
                                // front buffers. perhaps waits for v-sync.
        }

        cleanUp();
    }

    /**
     * Initialise OpenGL
     */
    private void initGL()
    {
        GL11.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, ((float) width / (float) height), 0.1f,
                100.0f);
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        GL11.glShadeModel(GL11.GL_SMOOTH); // Smooth shading
        GL11.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Black background
        GL11.glClearDepth(1.0f);
        GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GL11.glDepthFunc(GL11.GL_LEQUAL);
        GL11.glHint(GL11.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL11.GL_NICEST);
    }

    /**
     * Update Logic
     */
    private void updateLogic()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Render OpenGL
     */
    private void renderGL()
    {
        GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clear
                                                                            // The
                                                                            // Screen
                                                                            // And
                                                                            // The
                                                                            // Depth
                                                                            // Buffer
        GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The View

        GL11.glTranslatef(-1.5f, 0.0f, -6.0f); // Move Left 1.5 Units And Into
                                                // The Screen 6.0
        GL11.glRotatef(rtri, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES); // Drawing Using Triangles

        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Top
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Left
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Right

        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Top
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Left
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Bottom Right

        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Top
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Bottom Left
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Right

        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Top
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Bottom Left
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Bottom Right




        GL11.glEnd(); // Finished Drawing The Triangle


        GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The View

        GL11.glTranslatef(1.5f, 0.0f, -2.5f); // Move Right 3 Units

        GL11.glRotatef(rquad, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS); // Draw A Quad

        //TOP
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Top Left
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Top Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Left

        //FRONT
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Top Left
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Top Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Left

        //LEFT
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Top Left
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Top Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Bottom Left

        //RIGHT
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); // Top Left
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Top Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Bottom Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Left

        //BACK
        GL11.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Top Left
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f); // Top Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Bottom Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Bottom Left

        //BOTTOM
        GL11.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Top Left
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f); // Top Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Right
        GL11.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f); // Bottom Left




        GL11.glEnd(); // Done Drawing The Quad

        rtri += 0.5f;
        rquad += -0.5f;
    }

    /**
     * Poll Input
     */
    public void pollInput()
    {

        // scroll through key events
        while (Keyboard.next())
        {
            if (Keyboard.getEventKeyState())
            {
                if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)
                    closeRequested = true;
                else if (Keyboard.getEventKey() == Keyboard.KEY_F1)
                {
                        fullscreen = !fullscreen;
                    System.out.println(fullscreen);
                    setDisplayMode(width, height, fullscreen);
                }
            }

        }

        if (Display.isCloseRequested())
        {
            closeRequested = true;
        }
    }

    private void createWindow(String title, int width, int height,
            int colourDepth, boolean fullscreeen)
    {
        try
        {
            DisplayMode[] modes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();

            for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++)
            {

                DisplayMode current = modes[i];

                if (current.isFullscreenCapable())
                {
                    Display.setDisplayMode(current);
                }
                else
                    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
            }
            Display.setFullscreen(fullscreeen);
            Display.setTitle(title);
            Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);
            Display.create();
        }
        catch (LWJGLException e)
        {
            Sys.alert("Error", "Initialisation failed!\n\n" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void cleanUp()
    {
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public void setDisplayMode(int width, int height, boolean fullscreen)
    {

        // return if requested DisplayMode is already set
        if ((Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth() == width)
                && (Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight() == height)
                && (Display.isFullscreen() == fullscreen))
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            DisplayMode targetDisplayMode = null;

            if (fullscreen)
            {
                DisplayMode[] modes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();
                int freq = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++)
                {
                    DisplayMode current = modes[i];

                    if ((current.getWidth() == width)
                            && (current.getHeight() == height))
                    {
                        if ((targetDisplayMode == null)
                                || (current.getFrequency() >= freq))
                        {
                            if ((targetDisplayMode == null)
                                    || (current.getBitsPerPixel() > targetDisplayMode
                                            .getBitsPerPixel()))
                            {
                                targetDisplayMode = current;
                                freq = targetDisplayMode.getFrequency();
                            }
                        }

                        // if we've found a match for bpp and frequence against
                        // the
                        // original display mode then it's probably best to go
                        // for this one
                        // since it's most likely compatible with the monitor
                        if ((current.getBitsPerPixel() == Display
                                .getDesktopDisplayMode().getBitsPerPixel())
                                && (current.getFrequency() == Display
                                        .getDesktopDisplayMode().getFrequency()))
                        {
                            targetDisplayMode = current;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                targetDisplayMode = new DisplayMode(width, height);
            }

            if (targetDisplayMode == null)
            {
                System.out.println("Failed to find value mode: " + width + "x"
                        + height + " fs=" + fullscreen);
                return;
            }

            Display.setDisplayMode(targetDisplayMode);
            Display.setFullscreen(fullscreen);
        }
        catch (LWJGLException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to setup mode " + width + "x" + height
                    + " fullscreen=" + fullscreen + e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        DisplayExample displayExample = new DisplayExample();
        displayExample.start();
    }
}
```

[image: window]

Comment: Where's your resize event handler?

Comment: I'm not sure i know what that is.. The setDisplayMode() handles the window size/ makes it fullscreen etc.

Comment: You don't check the width and height of the available modes, perhaps that's the reason. You should match one available display mode and then not iterate further...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I make an LWJGL window resizable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206775/how-do-i-make-an-lwjgl-window-resizable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setDisplayMode only creates the window at an initial size. But when it gets resized the change must be applied to OpenGL.

I always recommend to forget about the idea of a "one time OpenGL initialization". IMHO the best practice is to set all state that directly affects drawing operations, and viewport and projection do belong to that state, *in the drawing code!* The whole code you have in `InitGL`  should be at the beginning of `renderGL`. `width` and `height` are variables to be set by the window resizing handler, or determined by querying window state.