# How to maximize screen in LWJGL/OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

I would like to maximize the screen.

Not to be confused with fullscreen, I mean the button directly to the left of the "close" button on almost all OS's.

I can find a `Display.setFullscreen(true)`, but no `Display.setMaximised()` or something similar.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

**Changing the display size**

The standard LWJGL fame is created in the size with which you initialize it. And set to not rezizable. You can change this by using  [`setResizable()`](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setResizable%28boolean%29). Now the user can resize the screen. Same for using a standart java `Frame` and passing it to [`Display.setParent()`](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setParent%28java.awt.Canvas%29) See [here](http://www.lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=Using_a_Resizeable_AWT_Frame_with_LWJGL)

And last but not least you can use [`setDisplayModeAndFullscreen()`](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.html#setDisplayModeAndFullscreen%28org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode%29) to pass a `DisplayMode`.

**Getting the right DisplayMode**

There are two way to get DisplayModes in LWJGL. Create them using a constructor or get them from the system.

For the former you just call `new DisplayMode(w,h)`. This mode object will be able to change the display windows size, but its `isFullscreenCapable()` will always return `false`. The best you can achieve with this is `windowed fullscreen`. This means a window is scaled to desktop size, set to undecorated and positioned at (0,0). You will have to acquire the current desktop size with standard Java and create a `DisplayMode` out of it.

 In other words you fit the display to the screen size.

The later means calling `Display.getAvailableDisplayModes()` You will receive an array of DisplayModes that your hardware supports. These *can* be fullscreen capable.
You will have to iterate trough them to get one you want to use. If you set one that has `isFullscreenCapable()` == true you will get a real fullscreen display.

This means the screen size is adjusted to fit the display.

Comment: Not what I am looking for. I need to set the display maximized without anybody pressing a button.

Comment: Thats what setDisplayModeAndFullscreen() can be used for.

Comment: Display.setDisplayModeAndFullscreen(new DisplayMode(200, 200)); is not working. The screen does not change size. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: According to the [source](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/opengl/Display.java) a simple call should suffice. This will only change the outer size of the window though. See [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249972/lwjgl-opengl-window-size-always-stays-the-same-despite-changing-width-and-height)

Comment: @user3764271 Did you check if 200x200 is a fullscreen capable mode?  See [isFullscreenCapable](http://lwjgl.org/javadoc/org/lwjgl/opengl/DisplayMode.html#isFullscreenCapable())  I doubt many displays support 200x200 mode

Comment: @Aaron it should change even if the mode is not fullscreen, but fall out of fullscreen if the previous mode was.

Comment: @DawnKeeper But I do not want fullscreen, so I am confused now.